# cannot setup TLPDB in /usr/local/texlive/2023

Tags: tlpdb, damaged

As for many years, today started to update `texlive`, after

> psudo tlmgr update --all

`tlmgr` asked to update itself, ok.

> psudo tlmgr update --self

Then retry

> psudo tlmgr update --all

and start getting several checksum errors, I stopped the update (guessing **that** repository wasn't updated yet) and started a new update to get **other** repository, but I got the message

> cannot setup TLPDB in /usr/local/texlive/2023 at /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 6895.

Is it something wrong with new version of `tlmgr` or  something got wrong with `TLPDB` ?

Comment: Is it possible that one or more of the various TEX environment variables (TEXMF, TEXMFHOME, etc.) has changed? I use a jailed (Linux) TeX on Android, which requires different paths than provided from TeXlive. In the past, an update could re-set the paths to the wrong values, then tlmgr would fail. Solution was to manually export the TEX environment paths in `.bashrc` file. This might not apply on Windows.

Comment: @rallg, PATH are in place in .profile, `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
`

Comment: Something similar happened with my system, about 6 months ago. I asked here at SE, but nobody else had the problem. Alas, I could only solve it by fresh TeX install. If you must do that as last resort, be sure that you do not lose anything in local TeX directories. But before you do that: Any possibility that you have something in a local TeX directory, interfering with update? TeX is not supposed to have that problem, but...

Comment: Killing an update might leave the database corrupted?

Comment: @cfr, That I think.

Comment: For some reason, I have been getting checksum errors for the last week or two. I can't figure out why. Sometimes, the update goes on without problems.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis I'm guessing something is slightly off with syncing somewhere, but I don't know enough about how it works.